# How to leave a Hazelcast cluster gracefully?

Tags: hazelcast

Currently, when I remove a node (e.g. ip-2) I simply call `HazelcastInstance.shutdown()`. But I still end up seeing a lot of warnings in the logs, e.g.

```
[ip-1]:5701 [xxx] [3.3.3] Removing connection to endpoint Address[ip-2]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException {Connection refused to address /ip-2:5701}, Error-Count: 5
[ip-1]:5701 [xxx] [3.3.3] This node does not have a connection to Member [ip-2]:5701
[ip-1]:5701 [xxx] [3.3.3] hz._hzInstance_1_xxx.IO.thread-in-0 Closing socket to endpoint Address[ip-2]:5701, Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
```

Is there a more proper way to remove nodes from a cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the recommended way. I guess the logging is a bit confusing.

Comment: It sure is confusing, because it's the same messages I'd expect to see if a node had just died! Open an issue at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/4223.